# ubuntu libvirt serial console requires ttyS0 restart to connect?

Tags: ubuntu, serial, linux-kvm

I'm attempting to configure serial access from my libvirt host to one of its guests.

I've configured the device on the guest and started it:

```
jsharpe@sel-app1:~$ cat /etc/init/ttyS0.conf 
# ttyS0 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on ttyS0 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc or RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 9600 ttyS0

jsharpe@sel-app1:~$ sudo restart ttyS0
ttyS0 start/running, process 767

jsharpe@sel-app1:~$ ps aux|grep ttyS0
root       767  0.2  0.0   6080   632 ttyS0    Ss+  17:20   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 9600 ttyS0
jsharpe    769  0.0  0.0   7624   904 pts/0    S+   17:20   0:00 grep --color=auto ttyS0
```

On the Host, I try to connect with virsh:

```
jsharpe@twoface:~ $ virsh console sel-app1
Connected to domain sel-app1
Escape character is ^]
```

... at this point, the host just hangs.  I can kill it with ^], but other keystrokes don't show up in the terminal.

Now, back over to guest, let's restart ttyS0:

```
jsharpe@sel-app1:~$ sudo restart ttyS0
ttyS0 start/running, process 772
jsharpe@sel-app1:~$ ps aux|grep ttyS0
root       772  1.0  0.0   6076   560 ttyS0    Ss+  17:23   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 9600 ttyS0
jsharpe    774  0.0  0.0   7624   904 pts/0    S+   17:23   0:00 grep --color=auto ttyS0
```

Great, back to the host:

```
jsharpe@twoface:~ $ virsh console sel-app1
Connected to domain sel-app1
Escape character is ^]

Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS sel-app1 ttyS0

sel-app1 login:
```

A login prompt?  So I have to restart ttyS0 *after* a connection has been attempted?  wtf.
Note that this isn't a timeout issue.  The host/console command will hang indefinitely.  It isn't until restarting ttyS0 that the connection happens.

Comment: What if you just connect and press Enter? Does the connection remain hung?

Comment: @grawity ugh, so simple :/  make that an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, serial ports don't have a standard means of detecting whether there is a terminal connected to the other side – or if they do, most virtual serial consoles simply don't bother implementing them. Hence the *agetty* instance for ttyS0 is started when the guest boots, and the login banner is simply sent to nowhere (to a disconnected port). When you finally connect, *agetty* isn't aware of that; it just sits there at a login prompt. You could try entering your username blindly and it would get sent.

Pressing a key, such as <kbd>Enter</kbd>, will cause *agetty* to re-display the login banner.